# Is IMAP/SMTP the way to find starred Gmail messages?

Tags: api, gmail

I want to create a page where anyone who sends me an email can input their email's message id, below,

```
Message-ID: <CAK2W-gCNJNRAME8+Q1CjbzbPo+JQFm5de6bkjaJ0JYwBoD2N8Q@mail.gmail.com>
```

in a form, then submit to see where in my queue of starred emails their message is, *e.g.* 26th.

I started researching the Gmail API, but either it's too limited to do what I want, or I don't understand how the API works. I only see three "APIs" that seem relevant to me: IMAP, SMTP, and Google Apps. (I don't even feel it's correct to call the first two *APIs*, but whatever, that's what I'm seeing online.) And from my understanding of IMAP/SMTP, it doesn't seem right that a *script* would transact via IMAP/SMTP; am I mistaken? As for the Google Apps front, well, it's only available to emails on Google Apps domains.

**Is it possible to retrieve messages (including all message headers) from Gmail via some API, *retaining its starred states*? If so, which, and how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are IMAP libraries for most scripting languages, so I think this can be considered an API. (SMTP is irrelevant, it's for *sending* mail, not reading it.)

The following documentation describes Google's IMAP extensions, and it looks like there's a way to view starred messages with its `XLIST` command.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions